# How can I get Data from NSFetchRequest without return Array (Core Data)

Tags: swift, core-data, fetchrequest

I don't want FetchRequest to return `[QuestionCD]` array. Can't FetchRequest return `QuestionCD` to me?

**each test has a unique title. There are 50 questions in total in a test. The title here determines the category of the questions.**

**With this function, I save the questions of that test according to the title of the selected test.**

**Is my Core Data model wrong? I want to categorize each test by title. I want questions to be returned to me according to the searched title. For example: "title: August Test 2". Please review my json construction and coreData models.**

**Save Category Function:**

```
func saveSelectedCategory(title: String) {
        let allCategory = QuestionCD(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
        allCategory.title = title
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to save selected category: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

After saving the category, I transfer the questions in the form of an array to the questions parameter in the same model and save it.

**Save Question Function:**

`[QuestionList]` is my custom model. I'm saving the questions I get from json to CoreData using this model.

```
func saveSelectedQuestion(questions: [QuestionList]) {
        
        let question = QuestionCD(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
        question.questions = questions
        
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to save selected category: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

**Get Selected Question:**

Here I am looking for the category of the selected title in QuestionCD according to the selected title.
You can review the json construction. eg title: "Ağustos Test 2"

**I don't want the return result to be `"[QuestionCD]"`. I want the returned result to be `QuestionCD`. Is this possible ?**

**You can examine the QuestionCD model from the Core Data Entites image.**
If QuestionCD is not an array, I can run it in a single ForEach to get the questions.

```
func getSelectedQuestion(questionID: String) -> [QuestionCD] {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<QuestionCD> = QuestionCD.fetchRequest()
        let search = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS %@", questionID)
        print("search: \(search)")
        fetchRequest.predicate = search
        do {
            return try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
```

[image]

**Core Data Entities:**

[image]

**JSON:**

```
{
  "allQuiz": [
    {
      "title":"Ağustos Test 1",
      "questions": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "question":"Şekle göre aşağıdakiler hangisi doğrudur",
          "isQuestionImage": true,
          "isSectionImage": false,
          "imageURL":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ehliyet-sinavim-01.appspot.com/o/Agustos%20Test%201%2F1.png?alt=media&token=2881447c-9081-4b13-a7ad-3ad097886b04",
          "sections": {
            "A":"2 numaralı aracın öncelikle geçmesi",
            "B":"1 numaralı aracın hızını arttırarak kavşağa girmesi",
            "C":"2 numaralı aracın 3 numaralı aracın geçmesini beklemesi",
            "D":"3 numaralı aracın 2 numaralı aracı ikaz ederek durdurması"
          },
          "selected":"",
          "correct": "A"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "question":"Akaryakıt istasyonundan yola çıkmak isteyen şekildeki 2 numaralı araç sürücüsü ne yapmalıdır ?",
          "isQuestionImage": true,
          "isSectionImage": false,
          "imageURL":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ehliyet-sinavim-01.appspot.com/o/Agustos%20Test%201%2F2.jpg?alt=media&token=94b833ff-3462-445a-9054-94b3cdaaa668",
          "sections": {
            "A":"Selektör yaparak 1 numarlı aracı durdurmalıdır.",
            "B":"Korna çalıp 1 numralı aracı yavaşlatmalıdır.",
            "C":"1 numaralı aracın geçmesini beklemelidir.",
            "D":"Geçiş hakkını kendi kullanmalıdır."
          },
          "selected":"",
          "correct": "C"
        },
        ...........
      ]
    },
    {
      "title":"Ağustos Test 2",
      "questions": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "question":"Şekle göre aşağıdakiler hangisi doğrudur",
          "isQuestionImage": true,
          "isSectionImage": false,
          "imageURL":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ehliyet-sinavim-01.appspot.com/o/Agustos%20Test%201%2F1.png?alt=media&token=*****-a7ad-3ad097886b04",
          "sections": {
            "A":"2 numaralı aracın öncelikle geçmesi",
            "B":"1 numaralı aracın hızını arttırarak kavşağa girmesi",
            "C":"2 numaralı aracın 3 numaralı aracın geçmesini beklemesi",
            "D":"3 numaralı aracın 2 numaralı aracı ikaz ederek durdurması"
          },
          "selected":"",
          "correct": "A"
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "question":"Akaryakıt istasyonundan yola çıkmak isteyen şekildeki 2 numaralı araç sürücüsü ne yapmalıdır ?",
          "isQuestionImage": true,
          "isSectionImage": false,
          "imageURL":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ehliyet-sinavim-01.appspot.com/o/Agustos%20Test%201%2F2.jpg?alt=media&token=*****-9054-94b3cdaaa668",
          "sections": {
            "A":"Selektör yaparak 1 numarlı aracı durdurmalıdır.",
            "B":"Korna çalıp 1 numralı aracı yavaşlatmalıdır.",
            "C":"1 numaralı aracın geçmesini beklemelidir.",
            "D":"Geçiş hakkını kendi kullanmalıdır."
          },
          "selected":"",
          "correct": "C"
        },
        ...........
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Model:**

```
class QuestionContainer: NSObject, Codable{
    
    var questions: Question
    
    init(questions: Question) {
        self.questions = questions
    }
}

class Question: NSObject, Codable {
    
    var title: String
    var questions: [QuestionList]
    
    init(title: String, questions: [QuestionList]) {
        self.title = title
        self.questions = questions
    }
}

public class QuestionList: NSObject, Codable {
    
    var id: String
    var question: String
    var isQuestionImage, isSectionImage: Bool
    var imageURL: String
    var imageData: Data?
    var sections: [QuestionSections.RawValue : String]
    var selected: String
    var correct: String
    
    init(id: String, question: String, isQuestionImage: Bool, isSectionImage: Bool, imageURL: String, sections: [QuestionSections.RawValue : String], selected: String, correct: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.question = question
        self.isQuestionImage = isQuestionImage
        self.isSectionImage = isSectionImage
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.sections = sections
        self.selected = selected
        self.correct = correct
    }
}
```

**CoreData Manager:**

```
class CoreDataManager: ObservableObject {
    let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init() {
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "EhliyetSinavim")
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Core Data Stre failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveSelectedCategory(title: String) {
        let allCategory = QuestionCD(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
        allCategory.title = title
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to save selected category: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func getSelectedCategory() -> [QuestionCD] {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<QuestionCD> = QuestionCD.fetchRequest()
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        do {
            return try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
    
    func searchInCategory(text: String) -> [QuestionCD] {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<QuestionCD> = QuestionCD.fetchRequest()
        let search = NSPredicate(format: "ANY title == %@", text)
        print("search: \(search)")
        fetchRequest.predicate = search
        print("request predicate: \(String(describing: fetchRequest.predicate))")
        do {
            return try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            print("ver bulunamadı \n")
            return []
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: ForQuestionCategory
    func saveSelectedQuestion(title: String, questions: [QuestionList]) {
        
        let question = QuestionCD(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
        question.title = title
        question.questions = questions
        
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to save selected category: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    func getSelectedQuestion(questionID: String) -> [QuestionCD] {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<QuestionCD> = QuestionCD.fetchRequest()
        let search = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS %@", questionID)
        print("search: \(search)")
        fetchRequest.predicate = search
        do {
            return try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        } catch {
            return []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t understand this question, why not make getSelectedQuestion return a single object (or nil) instead?

Comment: I couldn't return a single object from getSelectedQuestion. I shared the screenshot of the above error. The error says I need to return an array.

Answer (score 0):

You could return the first object from the array of fetched objects:

```
func getSelectedQuestion(questionID: String) -> QuestionCD? {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<QuestionCD> = QuestionCD.fetchRequest()
    let search = NSPredicate(format: "title CONTAINS %@", questionID)
    print("search: \(search)")
    fetchRequest.predicate = search
    do {
        return try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest).first
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried sir but I got error.. ```questions: <QuestionCD: 0x283f02d00> (entity: QuestionCD; id: 0xad7b5ca8d5f26601 <x-coredata://26C2094C-8A76-4D87-A1D0-19D9F43096A2/QuestionCD/p3>; data: {
    questions = nil;
    title = "A\U011fustos Test 2";
})``` I got title but I couldn't get questions Array

Comment: I think it is a separate problem. With this code you get one entry as you wanted and now you need to solve the problem with ``questions`` property.

Comment: Can I assign a custom array model to CoreData? otherwise i need to assign parameters one by one ?  (Save Function)


```func saveSelectedQuestion(questionTitle: String, questions: [QuestionList]) {
        let question = QuestionCD(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
        question.title = questionTitle
        question.questions = questions
        do {
            try persistentContainer.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to save selected category: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }```

Comment: In my projects I am using a custom ``Transformer`` for ``Transformable`` type. I am storing an array of [UIColor] there and placing it as a Custom Class (the way you did) is not working in my case

Comment: Sir I shared new question and you can download my very very simple project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68866385/core-datamultiple-nsentitydescriptions-claim-the-nsmanagedobject-subclass-co