# NSManagedObject conflicting with core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I built my iOS project using Xcode 13.2.1 & Swift 5.7. The project built successfully and my object was saved into Core Data. However, I received these warnings/messages in the output log.

Two questions:

1. +entity unable to disambiguate, can this be a problem? If so, how?
2. How can the warning be resolved?

[image: Error Message Log]

Comment: Try to search for the error online, here is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68866385/core-datamultiple-nsentitydescriptions-claim-the-nsmanagedobject-subclass-co And always post errors and such as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

looks like u have several CoreData entities with `@objc(User)` tag

or in xcdatamodel

[image]

another entity have User classname

Comment: Under CodeGen, Class Definition is the only option that builds successfully. However, I do not have the class defined in Swift, only in CoreData.